# How to look at all previous streaming results

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am new to Flink and am trying to find the best way to carry out a requirement we have. But before that let me set the scene

We are using Kafka where we would have a "Orders" topic which we would retain active orders in for 7 days (retention period on the Kafka topic)

We then need to use the [Kafka Connector in Apache Flink](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/)

What we would like to do whenever we see a new message coming in on Kafka on the "Orders" topic, would be to run a set of rules where we use the current "order" object from the Kafka topic and examine ALL previous state seen.

As I say I am not an Apache Flink master, but have used Kafka a fair bit, and underneath the scenes I know that we are really still just talking about Kafka producer (sink) and Kafka consumer (source) within Flink. As such I am just wondering how any of the operators work with Kafka and the commit log.

For example lets say I was to utilize some Flink operators to read from the Kafka input stream, bearing in mind for the output I want, we would need to read ALL previous state. So that kind of means we have read ALL the previous Kafka data, and possibly committed it. And knowing how Kafka works once the consumer has committed an offset, the consumer will only be able to read from that offset onwards, so effectively an previously seen messages on the input Kafka topic are effectively processed already, and are not visible to any future Flink operations.

An example of what I am trying to do is shown below, but this is just one example, and I have many such examples, all of which would need to use ALL the previous data as seen on the "Order" Kafka input topic.

I have found one example that talks about how to do aggregates in Flink using the `keyBy` followed by a `process` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54577863/flink-keyby-then-window-then-aggregate-all-results). Lets assume this works once for one example of a rule where I need to examine all prior data to perform some aggregations / lookbacks, which I could then store in Flink state using a `process` operator for example.

However like I say I have many such rules ALL of which must use ALL the previous data. This sounds like a job for Kafka consumer groups, where each new rule I have would require a new consumer group, such that each rule gets its own copy of the messages in the Kafka input topic. This is supported by Flink

```
    KafkaSource<String> source = KafkaSource.<String>builder()
        .setBootstrapServers(brokers)
        .setTopics("input-topic")
        .setGroupId("my-group")
        .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
        .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new SimpleStringSchema())
        .build();
```

So that part seems ok, but what I really don't know how to do is the part in Flink that would allow me to do this aggregating/lookup for a rule.

For example consider the following diagram

[image: DQ rule]

Lets say I have 20 such rules all of which must examine the previous state, what would the Flink operators be in the red rectangle in this diagram.

Should it work something like this

- We `KeyBy` order.OrderId
- We apply a time window
- We process (where we aggregate into some in memory data structure that allows us to get data we need to use to encode the rule, for example for the rule shown in diagram I would need Order.OrderEvent
  along with some input timestamp which could be stored in a List, and I could then check that list for the rule in question where I am able to iterate and build up a list of broken sub rules which would finally be emitted out to Kafka using Flink Kafka publisher. Obviously this might need to be stored in Flinks state store, which can be seen in this example for the `process` operator [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/datastream/operators/process_function/#example)

What I want to try and avoid

- replaying Kafka from start each time for a given rule
- I don't want the processing to take ages (as I say we are keeping Kafka records for 7 days and could expect millions of Orders in those 7 days)
- I have seen that Flink uses Checkpoints to ensure that the aggregated state is persisted. Do I need to do anything special in terms of Kafka for this to work?

Does this sound right? Any guidance of how to do this type of thing in Flink while still keeping Kafka happy would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Overall, I'd suggest dumping your data into some actual KV Store that lives outside of Kafka that you can perform lookups/joins against. That way, you wouldn't constantly be consuming the entire topic

Comment: such as redis? Issue is that Flink apps run on flink and I am not sure they can reach out to 3rd party KV stores like redis, as I think they really run in a sandbox

Comment: Honestly, it sounds like you're reimplementing event-sourced actors; I've worked on teams that started down that road in Flink and then decided to go a different way (specifically moving to a combination of Akka cluster sharding and persistence).

Comment: If you know all of the rules and the aggregations they require in advance, then you can use Flink to incrementally maintain/update those aggregations.

Comment: @LeviRamsey I used Akka a lot a previous place sadaly no can do here, if you are interested nice repo of mine here on it https://github.com/sachabarber/SachaBarber.AkkaExamples in Scala

Comment: @DavidAnderson thought as much, but what would this "aggregations" look like a custom "Processor" which is what I am leaning towards right now